# What are some good books and online resources for test-driven SharePoint development?

Tags: unit-testing, sharepoint, testing, testdriven.net

I am seeking articles, tutorials, examples, links, videos, books, or anything to get me started with the Test Driven SharePoint Development.

I am also interested to find out pros and cons of this practice and things to look for.

Comment: Can be closed as off-topic: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to understand it specific to Sharepoint. The concept of test-driven development is general enough to be applicable to any programming language or framework.

The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) can get you started, and there are plenty of links in google to go from there.

But, if you really want some Sharepoint specific articles, there is The Sharepoint Cowboy's [article](http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=179) and an article on [21 apps.](http://www.21apps.com/sharepoint/tdd-at-spbpc-slidedeck/)

Comment: I think SharePoint is a complex enough beast that specific advice on TDD practices is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Larry, "normal" test-driven applies to SharePoint just fine.

You should look at [TypeMock](https://www.typemock.com/) for your unit / integration tests. It's a unit-test / faking framework that allows you to fake SharePoint objects. Not sure if it's still the only one that does it, but it certainly is a good product.

I find that doing test-driven development in SharePoint is a bit more time-consuming than regular .NET TDD, mostly because SharePoint objects are more complex and harder to isolate. For example, a SharePoint list often depends on a content type, which depends on site columns, etc. It means that you have to put it a bit more work to get something working.

A big pro (in my eyes anyway) is that once your setup is done, you can work fast. Setting up your environment for a test (if you're doing it through the UI) is a pain. It takes a long time. For example, if you need to create your columns, then your content type though the UI every time you make a change to code that uses it, you'll lose a lot of time. Even more so if your test fails and you need to delete your content type because you broke something. Going with unit tests / fake SharePoint objects, you'll be able to do that in no time, plus you'll quickly get a better understanding of how the SharePoint objects work.